# Java: CPU Player Values Not Calculating

Tags: java, random

I've got a game that's quite simple: two players start with ten attack points and choose a number of points to attack the other player with the goal being to reduce the other player's life from 40 to zero. I've gotten the two player function to work just fine, but when it comes to generating the values for the computer player in single player more-- which is set using a switch-case-- it seems that no values are being generated. The difficulty flag is set with a radio button group, but no matter what the difficulty is set to, values for the computer player's attack aren't generated.

```
//This code calculates remaining attack/life points with the selected attack values.
//It's here that CPU player attack values SHOULD be set as well.
if(attackVal1 <= player1AtkPoints)
    {
        player1AtkPoints = player1AtkPoints - attackVal1;
    }
    else
        if(attackVal1 > player1AtkPoints)
        {
            attackVal1 = player1AtkPoints;
            player1AtkPoints = 0;
        }

    life2 = life2 - attackVal1;

    if(P2ACTIVE = false)
    {
        switch(difficultyFlag)
        {

            case 1:
                attackVal2 = cpuPlayer.nextInt(3) + 1;
                break;

            case 2:
                attackVal2 = cpuPlayer.nextInt(4) + 1;
                break;

            case 3:
                attackVal2 = cpuPlayer.nextInt(5) + 1;
                break;

            case 4:
                attackVal2 = cpuPlayer.nextInt(8) + 1;
                break;

            default:
                attackVal2 = cpuPlayer.nextInt(3)+ 1;
                break;
        }
    }

    if(attackVal2 <= player2AtkPoints)
    {
        player2AtkPoints = player2AtkPoints - attackVal2;
    }
    else
        if(attackVal2 > player2AtkPoints)
        {
            attackVal2 = player2AtkPoints;
            player2AtkPoints = 0;
        }

    life1 = life1 - attackVal2;
```

Above is the relevant code. The player one calculations work and reduce the player two life points for both single player and two player, with two player mode working in regards to reducing player one's life. It's only when it's set to single player that nothing happens to player one's life points, making it a one-sided battle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have assigned `false` to `P2ACTIVE` in this line, when you meant to compare it to `false`.

```
if(P2ACTIVE = false)
```

You could use the `==` comparison operator, but it's already a `boolean`, so just use the `!` operator:

```
if (!P2ACTIVE)
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I haven't seen that these last few days. I'll make the correction and hopefully it will work. Thanks for the hint in the ! operator. Never knew it worked that way.